# Table issue in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 like this:

```
Column      DataType
-----------------------
FID         numeric(18, 0)
Name        varchar(50)
DOB         datetime
MobileNo    numeric(18, 0)
EmailId     varchar(50)
add1        varchar(50)
add2        varchar(50)
add3        varchar(50)
Pincode     numeric(18, 0)
UpdateDate  datetime
```

In this table `FID` should be changed to `varchar(50)` without dropping (deleting) the table..

How to do this and also `FID` is set as primary key to the above table and also as a foreign key to other tables

Comment: `FID` is numeric now - ***why*** do you want to make it `varchar(50)` instead? Sounds like a **really bad idea** .... a number should **NOT** be stored in a `varchar` column! Also: if you change this, you'll also have to update **all** related tables that have a foreign key relation to this table... do you really want to do this??

Comment: Its a order from a higher authority to change the FID to varchar..they need FID as MU123..instead of 123

Comment: Can't you just add a separate, computed column like `ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD FID2 AS 'MU' + CAST(FID AS VARCHAR(20)))` and let this `FID` column alone??

Comment: But what  about the datatype its already numeric..how it will take that as varchar..?

Comment: If you want to change then keep FID field intact and as @marc_s said try putting another field. If you have already used `FID` else where, try renaming the field to say `KEY` that stores `numeric` value and `FID` as a new field that stores `varchar` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Tools->Options->designers->(Unmark)Prevent saving changes that require table recreation`

Answer (score 1):

As I said - I would leave the column `FID` as it is - otherwise, you'll have a ripple effect throughout your entire data model, and this is really really not what you want to do.

What you can do is this: create a new, separate column that contains that new prefix that the "hgiher ups" are so desperate for, and concatenates this with the `FID` value - but it's a separate column, and you don't need to change any of the references at all.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable 
ADD FID2 AS 'MU' + CAST(FID AS VARCHAR(20)) PERSISTED
```

With this, you'll get a `VARCHAR` typed new column called `FID2` which will have values like `MU1`, `MU2` ..... and so on - automatically, no changes necessary, no messy table re-creations and data copying.... it just works!

Comment: it need not be MU all the time the character may change..just in that case how to implement

Comment: @Shreyastg: have a column `Prefix` where you store the prefix, and then concatenate `Prefix` and `FID` into the new column ....

Comment: sorry to mention this at last..I am using asp.net with c# and FID is been generated from the code itself.In database i am just using for storage purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
Right click table -> Design -> Change the numeric(18, 0) to varchar(50) -> Save
```

It will ask for confirmation since changing from one data type to another removes certain precision values.

The best practice is to keep Primary and foriegn keys unique numbers. But you may opt for unique code values too which are `varchar` values

And one more thing, changing the primary key field datatype automatically changes the datatype of all relational foreign key fields in other tables too.

Comment: And again: since you're changing the datatype of this table's **primary key**, you will **also** have to update **ALL** tables referencing it!

Comment: In SQL Server 2008, it changes automatically. Any change in relational field changes all related fields too. I tried it and it worked that way.

Comment: I don't typically update my production databases in the visual table designer ...... if you do it with script, you have to remember to do it to all the related tables, too - manually

Comment: Yes using script, it is necessary to change all related tables. Better leaving it intact once it is populated with data.

Comment: sorry to mention this at last..I am using asp.net with c# and FID is been generated from the code itself.In database i am just using for storage purpose

Comment: Well then you need to edit your code right away. Even if you use your C# code behind to generate FID value, you can still change the database table structure right? It seems renaming your current FID to [Key] and placing a new `FID  - varchar(50)` field will be a better solution.